# command to move files another directory

Tags: linux, centos, command

I have a files that have a name somethings like this

**BK-Voice-1110694.wav, BK-Voice-1110695.wav, BK-Voice-1110696.wav,.... until BK-Voice-1110711.wav** . How to move the files BK-Voice-1110695 until BK-Voice-1110708 to another directory using command in Centos .I already run this command `mv *-1[110695-110708]* ../201501/ &` .But it move all the files to that directory.Anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mv BK-Voice-1110{695..708}.wav ../201501/ &
```